# Measuring Sets Intersection

Tags: algorithms

I need a fitness function saying how well Interval B fits inside Interval A. Both intervals are ordered continuous numbers going from Interval_Start to Interval_End, for example [1..100] or [1..55]. The only value in them really is start value and end value.

Interval A is always a fixed value, Interval B is a variable which I'm checking against Interval A. Some examples:

```
1. Interval A [1..100], Interval B [1..100] - match 100%
2. Interval A [1..100], Interval B [51..150] - match 50%
3. Interval A [1..50], Interval B [51..100] - match 0%
```

It gets more complex when interval lengths aren't the same as I need to use 'weights' to weight contributions of both similarity in length and the actually intersection, examples:

```
1. Interval A [1..100], Interval B[50..51] - I want it to to be close to 0%
2. Interval A [1..100], Interval B[10..90] - I want it to be 80% (not sure)
```

I wonder if there's existing algorithm used to measure the values I'm looking for. I'm no mathematician, and looking for a simple algo implementable in Javascript.

Comment: If $A=[a_1,a_2]$ and $B=[b_1,b_2]$, then $A\cap B= [max\{a_1,b_1\}, min\{a_2.b_2\}]$.

Comment: That is great but how do I get the actual fitness level? I know I'm @Meth forum but would appreciate if you could downgrade answers to boolean logic - ex. B.from <= A.to && A.from <= B.to is my translation for your answer

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any Javascript, but maybe you can take $ \frac{min\{a_2.b_2\}-max\{a_1,b_1\}}{a_2-a_1}\cdot 100$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jaccard Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) is the standard way of measuring set similarity,

In your case:

$$J(A,B)=\frac{|A\cap B|}{|A\cup B|}=\max{\{\frac{\min{\{a_2,b_2\}}-\max{\{a_1,b_1\}}}{\max{\{a_2,b_2\}}-\min{\{a_1,b_1\}}}},0\}$$

Comment: worked like a treat thanks man!